# Image registration in imageJ or matlab

Tags: matlab, imagej

I am looking for advice on how to automatically register image stacks acquired at different magnifications. Specially we need to align a small z-stack (~100um) taken of several brain cells in the live brain to a large z stack(~2mm) taken of the fixed brain. We want to be able to find back the cells that were previously imaged and take high resolution images of the staining to identify pre-synaptic inputs. Both the difference in magnification and rotation need to be taken into account as well as possible shrinkage or swelling. We would like an advice on the best way to do this using ImageJ or matlab.

Answer (score 0):

With ImageJ you might want to download the plugin StackReg:

http://bigwww.epfl.ch/thevenaz/stackreg/

or this nice macro code freely available:

http://www.plosone.org/article/info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pone.0053942

With matlab you are looking for imregister, imregtform and/or imwarp. Also look at the optimizer, which is used to define the type of transformation you wish to apply, for example translation, rigid body, etc. Examples on the matlab website are quite helpful. Please ask for more details if it's not clear.

EDIT:

Here is a simple code to register images stored in a sequence in a cell array with Matlab and the functions I mentionned:

```
clear 
clc


dialog_title = 'Select the directory containing the images to be processed'; % select images
folder_name = uigetdir('',dialog_title);

addpath(folder_name);

% select current folder
cd(folder_name);

ImagesToRead = dir('*.tif');

%preallocation

ImageCell = cell(1,length(ImagesToRead));

for i=1 : length(ImagesToRead)    
   ImageCell{i} = imread(ImagesToRead(i).name);    
end


optimizer = registration.optimizer.RegularStepGradientDescent; % here you can modify the default properties of the optimizer to suit your need/to adjust the parameters of registration.

[optimizer, metric]  = imregconfig('monomodal'); % for optical microscopy you need the 'monomodal' configuration.

RegisteredCell = cell(1,length(ImagesToRead));
for p = 2:length(ImagesToRead)

   moving = ImageCell{p}; % the image you want to register
   fixed = ImageCell{p-1}; % the image you are registering with

   movingONE = rgb2gray(moving(:,:,:)); % imregtform needs grayscale images
   fixedONE = rgb2gray(fixed(:,:,:));

   tform = imregtform(movingONE,fixedONE,'translation',optimizer,metric,'DisplayOptimization',true,'PyramidLevels',5);                   
   tform = affine2d(tform.T);

   RegisteredCell{p} = imwarp(moving,tform,'OutputView',imref2d(size(fixedONE))); % 

end
```

Now all your images are stored in the cell array 'RegisteredCell' and you can access each of them individually using RegisteredCell{YouImage} for example. Hope that helps!

Comment: @user3884830 so did you get a chance to try it?